# error in printing some of the columns from a list of list in python

Tags: python, list

I have this `list of list` in `python` and I want to print only the last 2 items from each list inside the main list using a single print statement. Here is my sample list: `[['Violet', 1, '219'], ['Yellow', 2, '235'],['Yellow', 1, '25']]`. What I essentially want to print for above sample data is this:

`Following are the rooms that are currently available - {Floor:1,Room Number: 219},{Floor:2,Room Number:235},{Floor:1,Room Number: 25}`

Here is a print statement I wrote:

`print("Following are the rooms that are currently available - - "+ str((",".join(lst))))`

When I execute this I get error as `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

I am still learning python and hence I am unable to figure out a way to print my list in the desired output I showed above and resolve this error. How can I do that?

Comment: what are the contents of the variable `lst`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inner_list_str = ["{Floor: %d,Room Number: %s}" % (floor, room_number) 
                  for _, floor, room_number in outer_list]
print "Following are the rooms that are currently available - " + ','.join(inner_list_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this :

```
lst = [['Violet', 1, '219'], ['Yellow', 2, '235'],['Yellow', 1, '25']]
res = "Following are the rooms that are currently available - - "
for room in lst:
    res += '{Floor:' + str(room[1]) + ', Room Number:' + str(room[2]) + '},'
print(res)
```

and if you want to remove the last ',' :

```
print(res[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 d = [['Violet', 1, '219'], ['Yellow', 2, '235'],['Yellow', 1, '25']]
 for L in d:
     print 'Floor ' + str(L[1])+ ', Room number  ' + L[2]
```

You can simply loop through the list and access the values with their indeces.

Answer (score 0):

You just use a `for` loop to loop through the list of lists, then print the second, and third elements:

```
rooms = [['Violet', 1, '219'], ['Yellow', 2, '235'],['Yellow', 1, '25']]
print("Following are the rooms that are currently available - ")
for room in rooms:
    print("{Floor:"+str(room[1])+",Room Number: "+str(room[2])+"},")
```

**Explanation:**

When you loop through the list of lists, `room` is being set to each individual list:

*First loop:* `room = ['Violet', 1, '219']`

*Second loop:* `room = ['Yellow', 2, '235']`

*Third loop:* `room = ['Yellow', 1, '25']`

Then inside the loop the code just prints out `room[1]` which is the second element in the list:

> ['Violet', **1**, '219']

and then `room[2]` which is the third:

> ['Violet', 1, **'219'**]

**Try it online:**

https://repl.it/It7Y/0